# getopts truncates argument value

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I need to pass a string value containing spaced as option in myscript.sh
The code looks like this:

```
while getopts "m:i:t:" OPTION
do
 case $OPTION in
     m)
         M=$OPTARG
         echo M: $M
         ;;
     i)
         I=$OPTARG
         echo I: $I
         ;;
     t)
         T=$OPTARG
         echo T: $T
         ;;
     ?)
         usage
         exit
         ;;
 esac
done
```

It works just fine when I call it directly on the command line:

```
./myscript.sh -m 1 -i '0 1 2 3' -t '2142'
M: 1
I: 0 1 2 3
T: 2142
```

However, I need to pass the -i as a string variable and I cannot get it to work. The string for option -i gets truncated and option -t does not even come through (possibly a new line).

```
I='0 1 2 3'
./myscript.sh -m 1 -i "'"$I"'" -t '2142'
M: 1
I: '0

I='0 1 2 3'
II="'"$(echo $I)"'"
./myscript.sh -m 1 -i $II -t '2142'
M: 1
I: '0
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you quoting like that when you try to run it? This I'm pretty sure this is what you meant to do:

```
./myscript.sh -m 1 -i "$I" -t 2142
```

Double quotes treats all characters inside them as literal, except a few things, including `$`, which allows variables to be expanded. Single quotes stop variable expansion as well. They each protect the other type of quote, so that `"'"` is just a `'` character, and `'"'` is just a `"` character.

This means that `"'"$I"'"` turns into `'0 1 2 3'`, with no special meaning for the single quotes, and no protection for the spaces - you might also write it as `\'0 1 2 3\'`. The spaces, being unprotected, split up words, so the first word is `\'0`. Your script therefore sees that as the value for the option, and `1`, `2`, and `3'` as extra arguments. You can see this if after your while loop you add `shift $((OPTIND - 1))` to shift away the parsed options, and then `echo "arguments: $@"` after your option parsing. You'll also see that since `getops` expects all the options together at the front, this has caused you to miss out on the `-t` option, treating it as an argument too.

Comment: +1 you're right, I blundered that one, heh.  I marked mine to be deleted because it was wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help! Sounds like you had good instincts, at least: if you see something split on spaces, it's probably a quoting problem.